# socket cant detect anyhting in a praw implicit authentication url

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, praw

im opening a socket server that hosts the reddit confirmation s that you can login to the application without compromising the bot and logging in with one sting called an access token that is in the url of the socket server and what i want to do it sake that access token from the url and display it into the socket server page but the server cant detect any variables inside of the url. Here is my [code](https://pastebin.com/iajGmem2) if you need it. it works when implicit is not part of the url generation, but as soon as i add implicit=True (which i need to, i plan on this being an app) it no longer works.
what i want: (about, this is for the non implicit)GET /?state=state&code=code HTTP/1.1.
what i get: GET / HTTP/1.1.
that is what happens when i do data = client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8").
it will return proper data when the url is generated with url = reddit.auth.url(scopes, state).
but  when i generate the url with url = reddit.auth.url(scopes, state, implicit=True).
the data will return GET / HTTP/1.1.
I need the access token to be recognized after the /.
I am using praw 7.1.0

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.15.2 Chrome/83.0.4103.122 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
DNT: 1
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br


/
/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/prawTest.py", line 81, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "path/prawTest.py", line 61, in main
    params = {
  File "path/prawTest.py", line 62, in <dictcomp>
    key: value for (key, value) in [token.split("=") for token in param_tokens]
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

It expects to see variables after the /.
Without implicit=Tru i get the following:

```
GET /?state=50470&code=code HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.15.2 Chrome/83.0.4103.122 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
DNT: 1
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

The implicit=True url looks like this:
http://localhost:8080/#access_token=token&token_type=bearer&state=39771&expires_in=3600&scope=%2A